Passing requests to background script
I am trying to create a plugin that just gets some data from a website and creates a Notion page. Apparently, I can't use the official SDK in the content_script because of CORS issues.
The solution should be to use chrome.runtime.sendMessage and chrome.runtime.onMessage, but this would just hide the Client interface and make it very difficult to use from the content_script
For example, this simple code, which has autocompletion:
function saveToNotion () {
  const result = await chrome.storage.local.get('notionToken')
  const notion = new Client({auth: result.notionToken})

  // THIS gives a CORRS error
  notion.databases.retrieve()
}

Would need to be changed to something like this:
// On content_script.tsx
function getDatabases () {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage('retrieve_databases')
}

// On background.tsx
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  const result = await chrome.storage.local.get('notionToken')
  const notion = new Client({auth: result.notionToken})

  return true
})

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.type === "retrieve_databases") {
    const result = await chrome.storage.local.get('notionToken')
    const notion = new Client({auth: result.notionToken})
    sendResponse(notion.databases.retrieve())
  }
  return true;
});

Is there any wrapper or any way to keep a typed interface like I would have in the first example?

You can spoof the network call made by Client e.g. override window.fetch with a function that calls chrome.runtime.sendMessage and returns the result, same for XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send.

Yeah, reading the docs it turns out you can pass a custom fetch function to Client()

I can create a custom fetch function to pass to the Client object:
export const bgFetch: SupportedFetch = (url, init) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
      {
        type: 'bgFetch',
        url: url,
        init: init,
      },
      (response) => {
        console.log("resolved response", response)
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          reject(new Error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message));
        } else {
          resolve({
            ok: response.ok,
            text: () => response.text,
            headers: response.headers,
            status: response.status,
          });
        }
      }
    );
  });
};

And then, in background.ts
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.type === 'bgFetch') {
    const url: SupportedRequestInfo = request.url;
    const init: SupportedRequestInit = request.init;

    fetch(url, init)
      .then((response) => {
          const toSend: SupportedResponse = response
          // You can only send JSON
          response.text().then((txt) => sendResponse({
            ok: response.ok,
            text: txt,
            headers: response.headers,
            status: response.status,
          }))
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Fetch error:', error);
        sendResponse({ ok: false, status: 500, text: () => Promise.resolve(error.message) });
      });

    // Return true to indicate that you want to send a response asynchronously
    return true;
  }
});

